# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Assume that $f$ is continuous at some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(a)<1$

Tags: analysis

Prove that there is an open interval $I$ containing $a$ such that $f(x)< 1$ for all $x \in I$

I'm really unsure of how to do this problem.  For some reason I feel like there is some sort of theorem for this, but I googled and could not find it.  Right now basically all I'm going on is that since $f$ is continuous, then we have $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Use the definition of continuity at $a$ taking $\epsilon<|f(a)-1|$.